# How do I format a single digit month in C# date formatting?

Tags: c#, datetime, date-formatting

In C#, if I run this code, it prints out `05`:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM"));
```

However, if I run this code, it prints out `May 16`:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("M"));
```

I'm looking for a date format that will print out `5`. How do I format a single digit month? To be clear, it would be 1 digit for months 1 to 9, and 2 digits for months 10 to 12.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`“%M"` should work. See [custom format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#UsingSingleSpecifiers)

---

Some explanation:

- The "M" can be part of a [custom format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#M_Specifier), where it means a "month number" in one or two digits
- But on itself it can also be a [standard format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#MonthDay) meaning a "month day pattern" - as the OP found out.

To resolve this ambiguity you can add a space, which makes it a custom format string, but also adds a space to the resulting value. Or you can add a `%`.

Right now (May) a `DateTime.Now.ToString("%M")` results in "5".

Answer (score -2):

Microsoft has some excellent documentation regarding how to format DateTime as string values over at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

The parameter you're looking for is `M` which would make the method call `DateTime.Now.ToString("M");`.

**Update:**
However, as pointed ut by Hans Keﬆing, this could give unexpected results in some situations which can be avoided by using a `%` in combination with the `M` as described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#UsingSingleSpecifiers

Comment: But M is interpreted as a short date format, as the OP found

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Thanks for pointing that out! I obviously didn't read the question properly.